# Google Drive query files by isAppAuthorized property

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Is it possible to use the file property `isAppAuthorized` as query term in the parameter `q` when searching for files using the `files.list` method?
I found the the table [File query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#file_properties) in the documentation section *Search query terms*, but I'm unsure if that table is meant as a complete list of supported query terms.

Testing the REST API with `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=isAppAuthorized = false` results in an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "Invalid Value",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "q"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid Value"
    }
}
```

I just want to make sure it's not an error on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google drive search functionality on file.list is very limited if you check [search terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#drive_properties) you will see that isAppAuthorized is not a searchable option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. So this table is meant as a complete list of supported query terms then.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it is the complete list it doesn't support much.

Comment: Alright. Additional filtering needs to be added on client side then.

Answer (score 2):

The scope "drive.file" already performs that function by default

Comment: To clarify, if your scope is not broader than "drive.file" then "list" only retrieves files with property "isAppAuthorized=true".